# How can I load all the data stored in the array, when the app starts again (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to implement a function that loads the stored data into the shopping list array, when the app starts, and a function that stores the current contents of my list when the button is pressed. I used `UserDefaults` class and it works for the second function (when the button is pressed) but not for the first one (when the app starts). If I restart the app and press the button, I see that only the last input was stored. How can I fix the code if I want to store all data from the array?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputEntered: UITextField!

    // keyboard gives up the first responder status and goes away if return is pressed

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        inputEntered.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    var shoppingList: [String] = []

    @IBAction func buttonAddToList(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let item = inputEntered.text, item.isEmpty == false { // need to make sure we have something here
            shoppingList.append(item) // store it in our data holder
        }
        inputEntered.text = nil // clean the textfield input

        print(shoppingList.last!) // print the last element to avoid duplicates on the console

        storeData()
    }

    // this function stores the current contents of my list when the button is pressed

    func storeData () {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(inputEntered.text, forKey: "Saved array")
        print(defaults)
    }

    // to call the function storeDate(), when the app restarts 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        inputEntered.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        storeData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you only seem to save the current `inputEntered` text, not the `shoppingList` data. Also I assume in `viewDidLoad` you call `loadData`, not `storeData`, correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your comment!  I tried this code -  defaults.set(shoppingList, forKey: "Saved array") - but it didn't help. I see the last input.   LoadData instead of storeData would be better but I don't know how I can load it....

Comment: @helicopter20 https://stackoverflow.com/a/61828637/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a getter and a setter to your array and persist your values to user defaults. This way you don't need to call storeData and or remembering to load the data when initialising your array:

```
var shoppingList: [String] {
    get {
        UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "shoppingList") ?? []
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "shoppingList")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I create a new class for shoppingList and class instances?

Comment: Just change `var shoppingList: [String] = []` to what I have posted above

Comment: Remove all other code that changes the user defaults

Comment: I am on my mobile now but I can check your code in about 10 minutes

Comment: @helicopter20 where are you displaying your list?

Comment: I am displaying it on the console

Comment: do `print(shoppingList)`

Comment: What you need is a table view controller embedded in a Navigation Controller with a UIBarButtonItem to add a new product to your list

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now how it is supposed to work :) I will try it with a table view controller.  Thank you for your advice and commitment!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `storeData()` in viewDidLoad, but inputEntered is empty then, so you are storing blank data.

Also, `defaults.set(inputEntered.text, forKey: "Saved array")` doesn't append new data onto the key -- it overwrites what is there.  So you are not storing the array, you are only storing the last value.

You need to store `shoppingList` to store the array.

Comment: Thanks you! I am trying to figure out how to store shoppingList and where....

Comment: Should I store the shoppingList  in this line defaults.set(shoppingList, forKey: "Saved array") ?  Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to turn the array into something that user defaults can store. shoppingList.joined(“\n”) and then use split to read it back

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I have got what you are asking for but have you tried looking into UITextFieldDelegate.

If you add this, it will ensure add the protocols of which I am sure there is a method that can be called when the user finishes editing text field.

Comment: I expected that UserDefaults would allow to store all the data from input. In my case all the elements of the array coming from the input. If I restart the app and click the button, I see only the last input (= the last element of the array). I would like to see all the values that I entered.